# Update KnockoutJS bound textbox with jQuery val()

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

So I'm using KnockoutJS with the [KO Mapping Plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) in a single page app and everything works great... except...

There is an option for the referring site to send some values in the query string to prepopulate a couple textboxes. I have a JS function that parses the query string and uses jQuery val() to populate the KO bound textbox value. However, the value never gets set.

Here is some pseudo-code on what I'm trying...

```
var jobTitle = "Ninja";

$("#jobTitle").val(jobTitle); // doesn't work

$("#jobTitle").val(jobTitle).change(); // doesn't work

$("#hiddenJobTitle").val(jobTitle); // works
```

Markup

```
<input id="jobTitle" type="text" data-bind="value: JobTitle" />

<input id="hiddenJobTitle" type="hidden" data-bind="value: JobTitle" />
```

An interesting note: I use the same code to set the value of a KO bound hidden field and it works fine.

Comment: Just curious can you not just use the `ko.observable()` syntax to set the value? Could just be an issue with `val()` mucking with the internals of ko. Just a thought.

Comment: I tried setting the property on the view model as a computed observable that would check for a query string value but that didn't work either. But that could be an issue with how it's set up using the KO mapping

Comment: Also of note.. if I take out the data-bind syntax from the html tag the value gets set properly. So it's definitely something in knockout rather than my getting/setting of the value.

Comment: Andy, could you post a bit more code, maybe your view model ? Alternatively, produce a jsfiddle reproducing your problem ?

Comment: Jalayn - Yea I'll see if I can get it in a fiddle. The viewmodel is very much a dummy since I'm using the mapping plugin. It simply creates a couple add / remove functions for a couple of the observable arrays.

Comment: @AndyBrudtkuhl Well, i made a very basic fiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/UAjY2/ The thing is that... it works.

Comment: @Jalayn haha me too -> http://jsfiddle.net/abrudtkuhl/j4L73/

Comment: So digging in deeper I think the issue is the sequence I'm loading scripts. Anyway I'm setting the value of the textbox via querystring on document ready before the view model is instantiated. I think this is where my problem lies. I'm working on a fix now where I call a getQueryStringValues function after I've loaded up the view model. Hopefully this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work for `$("#jobTitle").val(jobTitle)` is because jobTitle the knockout databind is actually the function.  If you were to inspect at that point in your code and see what jobtitle is returning you would see that it is a function.  You need to use `$("#jobTitle").val(jobTitle());`

in order to get the return of the knockout value.

Comment: jobTitle is simply a string variable i set from a query string value

Comment: I was assuming that in your real case it would not be a string since you stated that the above is pseudo code.  If it was coming across as a KO object or being assigned to a KO object then the above still holds true.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't an issue with KnockoutJS rather the sequence I load scripts and call functions.

I was setting the values of the textbox via the query string on document ready - before the view model that KO was binding to had been instantiated.

So I created a new function out of parse / set script and call it after I create the view model and bind it to KO.

Ideally I would have written an event handler / callback to watch for knockout binding to run it then - but could not find if knockout supports event callbacks like that. If they do - please let me know.

**Ideally** I would like to do something this so sequence doesn't matter

```
ko.on("bind", function(viewModel) {
 // this runs after knockout binds a view model
});
```